# Problem with multiple alignment defining a set

Tags: align, alignment, alignat

I have some problems defining a set in multiple lines. Here is the set:

[image]

The problem is that when written in this way, I go outside the margins.
I would like to define this set in multiple lines but with different alignments. Here is what I mean

[image]

I tried different combinations of `align` and `alignat` but I couldn't find the right one.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inner form `aligned` for this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\psi_t(v_t)
&= \bigl\{ (\psi_s)_{s=t,\dots,T-1} :
   \begin{aligned}[t]
   &S_t^\top \psi_t=v_t, \; \psi_t \in \Phi_t , \\
   &S_s^\top \psi_{s-1}=S_s^\top \psi_s, \; \psi_s \in \Phi_s , \; s=t+1,\dots,T-1 \bigr\}
   \end{aligned} \\
&= bla bla bla
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!. It's easier than I expected.